# Perl - Compare <STDIN> to Hash Key & Value

Tags: perl

I am trying to compare if two inputs ($name, $place) match the respective key and value of a hash. So, if $name matches a key and $place matches that key's value, "Correct" is printed. My code unfortunately is incorrect. Any suggestions? Thanks!

```
use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings;

my ($name, $place, %hash, %hash2);       
%hash = (
Dominic => 'Melbourne',
Stella => 'Beijing',
Alex => 'Oakland',
);
%hash2 = reverse %hash;

print "Enter name: ";
$name = <STDIN>;
print "Enter place: ";
$place = <STDIN>;


chomp ($name, $place);


if ($name eq $hash{$name} && $place eq $hash2{$place}) {
    print "Correct!\n";
} else {
    print "NO!\n";
}
```

Comment: You do not need `%hash2`. Try this: `exists $hash{$name} && $place eq $hash{$name}`

Comment: In other words, you are comparing name with place in the first condition, `Alex` with `$hash{Alex}` (which is `Oakland`). Same with the other condition. Just swap them, `$name eq $hash2{$place} && $place eq $hash{$name}`, or use `exists` as @Håkon suggests

Answer (score -1):

While a lot may be done to correct this (unrelated to the question), but here is the minimal solution necessary:

```
use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings;

my %hash = (
Dominic => 'Melbourne',
Stella => 'Beijing',
Alex => 'Oakland',
);

print "Enter name: ";
my $name = <STDIN>;
print "Enter place: ";
my $place = <STDIN>;

if ($name and $place) {
  chomp ($name, $place);
  if (exists($hash{$name}) and ($place eq $hash{$name})) {
      print "Correct!\n";
  } else {
      print "NO!\n";
  }
} else {
  print "ERROR: Both name and place required to make this work!";
}
```

As you are reading from STDIN you need to sanity check the input otherwise you get these problems in your result (not to mention the "Correct!" at the end) with unexpected input:

```
Enter name:
Enter place:
Use of uninitialized value $name in chomp at original.pl line 19.
Use of uninitialized value $place in chomp at original.pl line 19.
Use of uninitialized value $name in hash element at original.pl line 22.
Use of uninitialized value $name in string eq at original.pl line 22.
Use of uninitialized value in string eq at original.pl line 22.
Use of uninitialized value $place in hash element at original.pl line 22.
Use of uninitialized value $place in string eq at original.pl line 22.
Use of uninitialized value in string eq at original.pl line 22.
Correct!
```

Instead of this that should be generated with error checked code:

```
Enter name:
Enter place:
ERROR: Both name and place required to make this work!
```

PS: Please bear with my variable declaration changes, it's just OCD from me, unrelated to the question at hand. Like I said a lot could be done.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the elucidation! It seems I hadn't (perhaps still don't) understood the logic/function of the hash before using... Appreciate the help!